# How do I cause my nuget package to include <ExcludeAssets>runtime</ExcludeAssets> in the consumer's csproj file?

Tags: .net-core, nuget, csproj, nuspec

I am creating a NuGet package, and I would like, when this package is referenced, for the reference to look like this:

```
<PackageReference Include="A.PluginBase" Version="1.0.0">
    <ExcludeAssets>runtime</ExcludeAssets>
</PackageReference>
```

The article [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tutorials/creating-app-with-plugin-support#reference-a-plugin-interface-from-a-nuget-package) describes why this is necessary, but it does not describe how to create a package such that manual editing of the consumer's .csproj file is necessary. How do I accomplish this, ideally without having to create a .nuspec (i.e. by altering the package's .csproj)?